# IOS - tokBox audio not working after first session

Tags: ios, swift, audio, tokbox

I'm creating an app which enables online chat with a web app.
If I'm creating a session from fresh app start the session works properly.
but If a tokbox session already been created and I'm trying to create another one the audio doesn't work on both sides.
It seems to me like a memory deallocation issue, can anyone help with this?

Comment: Are you able to share some code snippets? Also, have you checked out our sample projects? There is a best practice implementation of a 1-1 video call https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples-swift

Comment: I am getting the same issue if we are calling from the same platform i.e Android to Android it is Working fine but if calling from ios to android then Video is displaying but audio is not getting audio us lost.